# Почему не заносятся биты в ArrayList?

Tags: java, файловая-система

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FileCopy {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        ArrayList<Integer> memoryList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String filePath1 = "d:\\1.txt";
        String filePath2 = "d:\\2.txt";

        FileInputStream fileInputStream1 = new FileInputStream(filePath1);
        FileInputStream fileInputStream2 = new FileInputStream(filePath2);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream1 = new FileOutputStream(filePath1);
        reader.close();
        while (fileInputStream1.available() > 0){

            int data = fileInputStream1.read();
            System.out.println(data);
            memoryList.add(data);

        }
        fileInputStream1.close();


        byte[]buffer = new byte [1000];
        while (fileInputStream2.available() > 0){

            int count = fileInputStream2.read(buffer);
            fileOutputStream1.write(buffer,0,count);

        }

        fileInputStream2.close();
        fileOutputStream1.close();

        try{

            FileWriter sw = new FileWriter(filePath1,true);

            for(Integer x: memoryList){

                sw.write(x);
                System.out.println("ok");
            }


            sw.close();

        }catch(Exception e){

            System.out.print(e.getMessage());

        }

    }
}
```

Требуется второй файл скопировать в первый, а первый файл(предварительно сохраненный в памяти) в конец дописать. Вопрос почему биты не добавляются в ArrayList?

Comment: что в итоге должно получиться в каждом файле по отдельности? я могу написать вам решение гораздо более простое, просто скажите мне, как должны выглядеть файлы.

Comment: Нужно первый файл сохранить в памяти, второй записать в первый(заменить) и в конец дописать первый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас слишком сложное решение для слишком простых вещей. Не надо изобретать велосипед, всё уже есть в библиотеке, нужно лишь научиться пользоваться.

Пожалуйста, моё решение:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        Path file1 = Paths.get("d:\\1.txt");
        Path file2 = Paths.get("d:\\2.txt");

        byte[] bytesFromFirstFile = Files.readAllBytes(file1);
        byte[] bytesFromSecondFile = Files.readAllBytes(file2);

        Files.write(file1, bytesFromSecondFile, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        Files.write(file1, bytesFromFirstFile, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    }
}
```

Comment: Решение да попроще, но не получается то что нужно. Спасибо большое за ответ. Вопрос только в том почему while (fileInputStream1.available() > 0){

            int data = fileInputStream1.read();
            System.out.println(data);
            memoryList.add(data);

        } вот это не работает.

Comment: @gnjbs Нашёл две причины: 1) FileOutputStream fileOutputStream1 = new FileOutputStream(filePath1, **true**); - добавление в конец файла; 2) используйте проверенный метод чтения потоков: int t; while((t = input.read()) != -1) memoryList.add(t); остальное в норме, единственное что у меня при считывании файла в лист считываются лишние символы, пока не понимаю, что за символы (пишутся вопросами) и откуда они взялись, попробуйте у себя. Есть вопросы - задавайте. Также буду признателен за "лучший ответ" если эти подсказки помогли.

Comment: Всё, у себя я полностью избавился от багов, надо было использовать кодировку ANSI, с UTF-8 были проблемы, чтобы их избежать надо было изменить ваш код, чего я не хотел делать.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FileCopy {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        ArrayList<Integer> memoryList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String filePath1 = reader.readLine();
        String filePath2 = reader.readLine();

        FileInputStream fileInputStream1 = new FileInputStream(filePath1);

        while (fileInputStream1.available()>0) {
            int data = fileInputStream1.read();
            memoryList.add(data);

        }
        fileInputStream1.close();


        FileInputStream fileInputStream2 = new FileInputStream(filePath2);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream1 = new FileOutputStream(filePath1);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
        while (fileInputStream2.available() > 0) {

            int count = fileInputStream2.read(buffer);
            fileOutputStream1.write(buffer, 0, count);

        }

        fileInputStream2.close();
        fileOutputStream1.close();


        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filePath1,true);
        for(Integer x: memoryList){

            fileWriter.write(x);

        }
        fileWriter.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вот так работает правильно.